# mypy throws error for abstractmethod created with decorator

Tags: python, decorator, mypy, abc

I have a decorator that creates an abstractmethod from a simple method. It works as I'd expect, however if I run mypy, it tells me this:

```
mypy_try.py:20: error: Missing return statement  [empty-body]
mypy_try.py:20: note: If the method is meant to be abstract, use @abc.abstractmethod
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

My code:

```py
import abc
from functools import wraps

import pytest


def make_it_abstract(method_to_decorate):

    @wraps(method_to_decorate)
    def decorated_method(*method_args, **method_kwargs):
        return method_to_decorate(*method_args, **method_kwargs)

    return abc.abstractmethod(decorated_method)


class MyInterfaceClass(abc.ABC):

    @make_it_abstract
    # @abc.abstractmethod
    def my_method(self, value: int) -> int:
        ...


def test_abstract_method():

    class MyImplementationClass(MyInterfaceClass):
        pass

    with pytest.raises(
            TypeError,
            match="Can't instantiate abstract class MyImplementationClass with abstract method my_method"
    ):

        MyImplementationClass()

    class MyImplementationClass(MyInterfaceClass):
        def my_method(self, value: int) -> float:
            return value +1

    assert 43 == MyImplementationClass().my_method(42)
```

If I use the `abc.abstractmethod` decorator, it works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doind everything fine, but `mypy` is not smart enough to figure out that your decorator calls `abc.abstractmethod` (and this is almost impossible, in fact, even if you've typed the decorator).

According to code in [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/abc.pyi#L26), `abstractmethod` is a no-op for type checkers. So `mypy` just detects the usage of `abc.abstractmethod` as decorator directly, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/e0a37fa2d9654fae61799c09b5c84630309f8735/mypy/semanal.py#L1362). `refers_to_fullname` method expands aliases and basically checks if node name is equal to one of requested names.

So even the following raises the same error:

```
ab = abc.abstractmethod

class MyInterfaceClass(abc.ABC):
    @ab
    def my_method(self, value: int) -> int:  # E: Missing return statement  [empty-body]
        ...
```

Comment: I see. And can this be filtered somehow? `disable_error_code = ["empty-body"]` would filter all empty-body errors I guess

Comment: Yes, so either this (because this error is pretty rare, so I doubt you can't live without it), or `# type: ignore[empty-body]` on the corresponding line, as usual.

Comment: Also there is `# mypy: disable-error-code=empty-body` at top level AFAIC, so you can disable this for the whole file with this comment.